# UI clicker/recorder/playback c#

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests

I'm trying to build a UI screen clicker recorder/playback in c# to automate testing a number of applications that we have to update on a monthly basis.

The tests can be quite in depth so has to be accurate. I know there is autoit that has a recorder but we were hoping to build our own(recorder) so we can put our own branding and features on it.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To build an automated test application of any kind,you will have at least three applications that can be implemented in whether in conpletely different assemblies in one solution or SOA (wcf services using TCP for communication) .Tester application,global windows event handler (global hooks), and application communicator app.TesterApp would trigger the events of starting and stopping and playing back the mouse and keyboard interactions of end user.GlobalEventHandlerApp will do the actual task of listening to mouse and keyboard interactions and dispatch them to ApplicationCommunicatorApp which has the facilities to talk to app being tested and conform the coordinates of mouse interaction actions to target app coordinates,for proper targetting of controls on the end application.

Comment: Thank you for you reply sounds like a lot of work.. Maybe there is some out of the box solution? i know Microsoft released WinAppDriver UI Recorder just unsure how to make it a standalone app rather that csharp playback tool.

Comment: Yes, but actually I'm in the middle of doing such a task, and I can write the whole code from scratch for you (at least modules).

Comment: And forward it to stack overflow,and the whole code to github.

Comment: That sounds amazing and the perfect solution :)

Comment: Yeah, quite challenging.